# Error of incomplete type is not allowed, declaring struct in another cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I declared a `struct` within the same `.cpp` file of the `main()` function. Then no error occurs.

But the error of "*incomplete type is not allowed*" occurs if I put the `struct` in another `.cpp` file.

**file2.cpp:**

```
struct a_point {
    float x, y;
};
```

**file2.h :**

```
struct a_point;
```

**file1.cpp** :

```
#include "file2.h"

int main(){

    a_point  pnt_arr[5]; // error occurs, in visual studio 2017

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Struct definitions go in headers.

Comment: @PasserBy, yes, I put `a_point` in `file2.h` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Struct definitions are only in the header file.

**file2.h :**

```
struct a_point {
    float x, y;
};
```

Delete the content in **file2.cpp** and no change is needed in **file1.cpp**.

Comment: This answer only explains how to fix the issue, but does not explain what the root issue actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You are [**forward declaring**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct#Forward_declaration) the struct's type in `file2.h`.

While compiling `file1.cpp`, when `file2.h` is included, the compiler sees the forward declaration and so knows that the struct type *exists*, which is good enough only for declaring pointers (`a_point*`) and references (`a_point&`) to the struct type, that is all.

However, the compiler does not know *what the struct's content looks like* (the compiler has no concept of `file2.cpp` while compiling `file1.cpp`), so the struct type is *incomplete* within the context of `file1.cpp`, and thus the compiler can't create any *instances* of the struct, such as for your array.

By moving the full declaration of the struct into `file2.h`, that is no longer the case.